# Is there an alternative for kernel32.dll for Mac?

Tags: c#, .net, macos, dll-injection

I am trying to follow this tutorial:
https://codingvision.net/security/c-inject-a-dll-into-a-process-w-createremotethread
but kernel32.dll and its functions can only be used on windows.
What can I use instead to inject dlls on mac?

Comment: You just won't be able to do it the same way on OS X I don't believe, you'd need to look at dylib loading within processes on *nix systems. This is not c# or .net issue per se, it's that you need to find an OS specific technique (and even then I have some doubts if it is as easy to do)

Answer (score 0):

If you are injecting `kernel32` then it means that you are actually injecting a native library designed for Windows. There is no 1-to-1 alternative apart from possibly ones within libraries like WINE, but avoid such hacks.

Instead consider finding an alternative in the API of the actual system. You should find the respective method in the API of the system which you are currently running and conditionally execute different calls.

Yet be sure to know that the best approach would bo to AVOID using direct system calls and operate only within .NET, especially that if you find a way to execute required things only using .NET libraries then there is a high chance of migration to **.NET Core** which is designed to work on all three major systems without a problem (especially for web and console applications).

So to sum up:

- there is no kernel32.dll for MacOS
- you need to find a respective function in the API of MacOS which will do the same as the method which you have called from Kernel32
- the best thing is to avoid usage of Kernel32 and try to find a respective call within .NET libraries

Answer (score 0):

Once upon a time you could simply use the Mach call `task_for_pid()` but that stopped working years ago when Apple first started paying attention to security. Then for a few years you could still force the dynamic linker to load a `.dylib` into an executable when it launched by setting some environment variables, but then Apple put a stop to that too, as they continued to crack down on security holes.

For the most part you can't do this anymore, or at least not easily. Especially with things like System Integrity Protection enabled. (I mean you could still create a kernel extension and do it there, except Apple now requires that all kernel extensions be signed with a special entitlement and they're pretty much not giving out that entitlement anymore.)